# Shared data structure between C++ and Fortran, good on C++ side, bad on Fortran side

Tags: c++, fortran

I am trying to pass a structure "stuff" from C++ to Fortran.  "stuff" has a member "gef" which contains two variables, "name" and "extra".  Before the call to the Fortran routine test2, both stuff.gef and stuff_gef are good,  But when I enter the Fortran, the "name" and "extra" variables are bad.

Update: the original problem is solved, however I was recommended to use BIND(C) on the Fortran structures.  I tried but got a compilation error as pointers aren't allowed with the BIND(C) qualifier.  I need the pointer variable to map the external (_ext) Fortran structure to C++ structure, as the internal version has allocatable arrays which aren't interop with C++

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    struct t_stuff_gef {
      char   name[256];
      double extra;
      double* p_var;
    };
    struct t_stuff {
      t_stuff_gef gef;
    };
    void test2(t_stuff *stuff);
}

int main()
{
    t_stuff stuff;

    strcpy_s(stuff.gef.name, sizeof(stuff.gef.name), "Teststuff");
    stuff.gef.extra = 100.0;
    stuff.gef.p_var = new double[2];
    stuff.gef.p_var[0] = 123.0;
    stuff.gef.p_var[1] = 456.0;
    test2(&stuff);
}
```

Fortran code:

```
module ftncode_mod
   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
   implicit none

!--external structure, same as C
   type, public :: t_stuff_gef_ext
     character(1)     :: name(256)
     real(8)          :: extra
     real(8), pointer :: var
   end type t_stuff_gef_ext

!--internal structure, to be be populated from the interface structure above
   type, public :: t_stuff_gef
     character(1)         :: name(256)
     real(8)              :: extra
     real(8), allocatable :: var(:)
   end type t_stuff_gef

   type, public :: t_stuff_ext
     type(t_stuff_gef_ext) :: gef
   end type t_stuff_ext

    contains
      subroutine test2(stuff_ext) bind(C)
      !DEC$ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: test2
        type(t_stuff_ext), target , intent(in) :: stuff_ext
        type(t_stuff_gef) :: stuff_gef
        integer :: i
        real(8) :: k
        pointer (p_k,k)
        p_k = loc(stuff_ext%gef%var)
        allocate(stuff_gef%var(2))
        do i = 1, 2
          stuff_gef%var(i) = k
          p_k = p_k + sizeof(k)
        enddo

        print *, stuff_gef%var(1)
        print *, stuff_gef%var(2)

        return
      end

end module
```

This code works, but only without the BIND(C) qualifier.

Comment: Please be more specific than "bad". What exactly are they?

Comment: I don't know fortran but my guess would be that in your c declaration `t_stuff` contains a pointer but in fortran it contains the actual structure

Comment: why does `t_stuff` only contain a pointer?

Comment: Why aren't you using the C interoperabilty features in the Fortran code? Your types should have the `bind(C)` attribute. Moreover the `get` component is a pointer in C, but a type in Fortran: it cannot match.

Comment: @PierU I added the bind(C) to the 2 Fortran types

Comment: @molbdnilo the name (Teststuff) appears at position 41 in name on the Fortran side, chars before are garbage, as is the "extra " variable

Comment: Why do you have `use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding` (unnecessarily, the second time), when you aren't using anything from that module? You _should_ be using things from the module, like `c_double` (instead of `8`)` and `c_ptr` and perhaps even `c_char`, but you aren't.

Comment: @PierU I fixed the pointer with gef, and it now works.  I will post the answer... aah I see you have already.

Answer (score 3):

The following code does what you want. The important point is to bind the Fortran types to C, and to declare a `c_ptr` when a pointer is declared on the C side.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    struct t_stuff_gef {
      char   name[256];
      double extra;
    };
    struct t_stuff {
      t_stuff_gef *gef;
    };
    void test2(t_stuff *stuff);
}

int main()
{
    t_stuff stuff;
    t_stuff_gef stuff_gef;

    strncpy(stuff_gef.name,"Teststuff",256);
    stuff_gef.extra = 100.0;

    stuff.gef = &stuff_gef;

    printf("%s\n%f\n\n",stuff_gef.name,stuff_gef.extra);
    test2(&stuff);
}
```

```
module ftncode_mod
   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
   implicit none

   type, public, bind(C) :: t_stuff_gef_ext
     character(256) :: name
     real(c_double) :: extra
   end type t_stuff_gef_ext

   type, public, bind(C) :: t_stuff_ext
     type(c_ptr) :: gef_cptr   ! for consistency with the C struct
   end type t_stuff_ext

   contains
      subroutine test2(stuff_ext) bind(C)
        type(t_stuff_ext) , intent(in) :: stuff_ext
        type(t_stuff_gef_ext), pointer :: gef

        call c_f_pointer(stuff_ext%gef_cptr, gef) ! convert the C pointer to a Fortran pointer

        write(*,*) gef%name
        write(*,*) gef%extra
      end

end module
```

Compilation:

```
%gfortran -c cfinteropf.f90 ; g++ cfinterop.cpp cfinteropf.o -lgfortran && a.out
Teststuff
100.000000

 Teststuff
   100.00000000000000
```

Comment: I got it working by fixing the gef pointer.  I don't use C_PTR on the Fortran side, it works using type(t_stuff_gef_ext) :: gef and without the c_f_pointer call.  Is the C_PTR solution recommended?  I also did away with the t_stuff_gef structure on the C side and used stuff.gef directly.

Comment: @Adrian `c_ptr` is needed only if the C side component is a pointer.

Comment: A minor nitpick, the character declaration could be explicit about the use of the kind: `character(c_char,256) :: name`. Additionally, you could add `const` in the C prototype of `test2` to match the intention of the `intent(in)` attribute.

Answer (score -3):

My solution.

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    struct t_stuff_gef {
      char   name[256];
      double extra;
    };
    struct t_stuff {
      t_stuff_gef gef;
    };
    void test2(t_stuff *stuff);
}

int main()
{
    t_stuff stuff;

    strcpy_s(stuff.gef.name, sizeof(stuff.gef.name), "Teststuff");
    stuff.gef.extra = 100.0;

    test2(&stuff);
}
```

Fortran Code:

```
module ftncode_mod
   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
   implicit none

   type, public :: t_stuff_gef_ext
     character(1)   :: name(256)
     real(8)        :: extra
   end type t_stuff_gef_ext

   type, public :: t_stuff_ext
     type(t_stuff_gef_ext) :: gef
   end type t_stuff_ext

    contains
      subroutine test2(stuff_ext) bind(C)
      !DEC$ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: test2
        type(t_stuff_ext), target , intent(in) :: stuff_ext
        continue       
        return
      end

end module
```

Comment: You are missing the `bind(C)` on the types (without them the code doesn't even compile with gfortran)

Comment: @PierU I was wondering if they were needed, as it works without them

Comment: I don't know which compiler you are using, but as I said it gfortran reports an error if they are not present. Maybe it works with your compiler, but it's only by chance, you cannot assume that it will work with any compiler, or with any type definition. Try changing the length of your string from 256 to 255 characters for instance.

Comment: The Intel compilers (which `!DEC$` implies you are using) are very permissive about C interoperability in Fortran code. For `t_stuff_ext` without `bind(c)` the code presented is not valid Fortran even if ifx/ifort accept it. As commented, other compilers will refuse to compile this incorrect code and there's no guarantee that a compiler which does compile it will reliably do what you want. (It's usually better to write standard-conforming code for precisely these reasons.)

Comment: Yes, Intel compiler.  I tried to add bind(C) in the master project, but the compilation failed as I have a real(8), pointer :: p_var in t_stuff_def_ext.  with "error #8080: Each component of a derived type with the BIND attribute shall be a nonpointer, nonallocatable data component with interoperable type and type parameters.   [P_VAR]"

Comment: @PierU I updated the C++ and Fortran code above to include the extra array variable in t_stuff_gef_ext.  But as allocatable arrays are not interop, I needed two structures on the Fortran side, the external (C compatible - _ext) and internal version (without the _ext) which contains the allocatable array.  And a bit of code to copy the array contents from _ext to internal.

Comment: @Adrian, once again (you already did that in your previous question) please do NOT continuously update/change your initial code at a point where the question gets completely different from the initial one and the initial answers get pointless. If necessary ask a new question.

Comment: @Adrian: your new code is crazy, you are mixing C pointers, Fortran pointers, and Cray pointers (which are non-standard), and all this relying only on the tolerances of ifort... I won't comment more here, ask a new question.

Comment: ok sorry @PierU I wasn't sure how to update the question.  I will create a new post.

Comment: @PierU I created a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75242877/shared-data-structure-between-c-and-fortran-adding-allocatable-arrays

Comment: Downvoted this answer because as others have already said, the Fortran code shown is non-portable.