# Shared data structure between C++ and Fortran: adding allocatable arrays

Tags: c++, fortran, interop

This is an extension to my previous post passing a character and double from C++ to Fortran, by mapping the same data structure.  It adds an allocatable array.  As this is not interop, I have to create two structures on the Fortran side, one that maps to the C++ structure (interop) and another that contains the allocatable array.  Then I allocate the internal array "var" and copy from the external version (which maps from the C++ version) to the internal one using a technique recommended here [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Passing-strings-and-allocatable-arrays-in-a-structure-between-C/m-p/1415432#M162817).  This works fine.

However in the previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75233971/shared-data-structure-between-c-and-fortran-good-on-c-side-bad-on-fortran/75234734#75234734) (without the allocatable array) I was told that I have to use BIND(C) on the external structure t_stuff_gef_ext.  When I add BIND(C) I get a compiler error: "error #8080: Each component of a derived type with the BIND attribute shall be a nonpointer, nonallocatable data component with interoperable type and type parameters. [P_VAR]"

C Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    struct t_stuff_gef {
      char   name[256];
      double extra;
      double* p_var;
    };
    struct t_stuff {
      t_stuff_gef gef;
    };
    void test2(t_stuff *stuff);
}

int main()
{
    t_stuff stuff;

    strcpy_s(stuff.gef.name, sizeof(stuff.gef.name), "Teststuff");
    stuff.gef.extra = 100.0;
    stuff.gef.p_var = new double[2];
    stuff.gef.p_var[0] = 123.0;
    stuff.gef.p_var[1] = 456.0;
    test2(&stuff);
}
```

Fortran code:

```
module ftncode_mod
   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
   implicit none

!--external structure, same as C
   type, public :: t_stuff_gef_ext
     character(1)     :: name(256)
     real(8)          :: extra
     real(8), pointer :: var
   end type t_stuff_gef_ext

!--internal structure, to be be populated from the interface structure above
   type, public :: t_stuff_gef
     character(1)     :: name(256)
     real(8)          :: extra
     real(8), allocatable :: var(:)
   end type t_stuff_gef

   type, public :: t_stuff_ext
     type(t_stuff_gef_ext) :: gef
   end type t_stuff_ext

   contains
      subroutine test2(stuff_ext) bind(C)
      !DEC$ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: test2
        type(t_stuff_ext), target, intent(in) :: stuff_ext
        type(t_stuff_gef) :: stuff_gef
        integer :: i
        real(8) :: k
        pointer (p_k,k)
        p_k = loc(stuff_ext%gef%var)
        allocate(stuff_gef%var(2))
        do i = 1, 2
          stuff_gef%var(i) = k
          p_k = p_k + sizeof(k)
        enddo
        print *, stuff_gef%var(1)
        print *, stuff_gef%var(2)
        return
      end

end module
```

Comment: No time to go into detail of this at the moment but note `real(8)` is potentially not interoperable and poor practice anyway - you should *never* use literal constants for Fortran kinds. Here you almost certainly want `Real( c_double )`. But the Cray pointer and `loc` makes it non-standard anyway, because of that please tell us what compiler and version you are using, as we may need to know that to test your program.

Comment: Intel Fortran compiler Version 2021.6.0 Build 20220226_000000, Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.18

Comment: Although StackOverflow is great, the strict Q/A format is not always adapted when learning and when extensive discussions are needed. So I just want to to raise your attention to the [Fortran Discourse forum](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/), which is also a great place to get help.

Answer (score 3):

I am posting a solution inspired by ivanpribec answer in this discussion: https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/allocate-interoperability-and-c-descriptors/5088/5

Context: we have an existing Fortran library that we don't want to modify, with some allocatable arrays in derived types, and we want to access the allocatable arrays from C, without data duplication. The idea is to write wrappers and leave the original library untouched :

```
! ORIGINAL LIBRARY
module ftncode
   implicit none

   integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1d0)

   type :: t_stuff_gef
     character(len=256) :: name
     real(dp)           :: extra
     real(dp), allocatable :: var(:)
   end type t_stuff_gef

   type :: t_stuff
     type(t_stuff_gef) :: gef
   end type t_stuff

   contains

      subroutine test2(stuff)
        type(t_stuff), intent(in) :: stuff
        integer :: i
        print *, stuff%gef%name
        print *, stuff%gef%extra
        do i = 1, size(stuff%gef%var)
           print *, stuff%gef%var(i)
        end do
      end

end module
```

```
! WRAPPER MODULE
module ftncode_wrap
   use ISO_C_BINDING
   use ftncode
   implicit none

   contains

      type(c_ptr) function stuff_create(n) bind(C)
         integer(c_int), intent(in), value :: n
         type(t_stuff), pointer :: p
         allocate(p)
         allocate(p%gef%var(n))
         stuff_create = c_loc(p)
      end function

      subroutine stuff_setname(pc,cstring) bind(C)
         type(c_ptr), intent(in), value :: pc    
         character(kind=c_char,len=1), intent(in) :: cstring(256)
         integer :: i
         type(t_stuff), pointer :: p
         call c_f_pointer(pc,p)
         do i = 1, 256
            p%gef%name(i:i) = cstring(i)
         end do
      end subroutine

      subroutine stuff_setextra(pc,extra) bind(C)
         type(c_ptr)   , intent(in), value :: pc    
         real(c_double), intent(in), value :: extra
         type(t_stuff), pointer :: p
         call c_f_pointer(pc,p)
         p%gef%extra = extra
      end subroutine

      type(c_ptr) function stuff_getvar(pc) bind(C)
         type(c_ptr), intent(in), value :: pc         
         type(t_stuff), pointer :: p
         call c_f_pointer(pc,p)
         stuff_getvar = c_loc(p%gef%var)
      end function 

      subroutine stuff_test2(pc) bind(C)
         type(c_ptr), intent(in), value :: pc
         type(t_stuff), pointer :: p
         call c_f_pointer(pc,p)
         call test2(p)
      end subroutine

      subroutine stuff_free(pc) bind(C)
         type(c_ptr), intent(inout) :: pc         
         type(t_stuff), pointer :: p
         call c_f_pointer(pc,p)
         deallocate( p%gef%var )
         deallocate( p )
         pc = c_null_ptr
      end subroutine
         
end module
```

C code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    void* stuff_create(int n);
    void  stuff_setname(void* pc, char* cstring);
    void  stuff_setextra(void* pc,double extra);
    void* stuff_getvar(void* pc);
    void  stuff_test2(void* pc);
    void  stuff_free(void** pc);

int main()
{
    char name[256];
    strncpy(name, "Teststuff",256);

    void* stuff = stuff_create(3);
    stuff_setname(stuff,name);
    stuff_setextra(stuff,100.0);

    double* var = (double*)stuff_getvar(stuff);
    var[0] = 123.0;
    var[1] = 456.0;
    var[2] = 789.0;

    stuff_test2(stuff);

    stuff_free(&stuff);
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
% gfortran -c interop2f.f90 && gcc interop2c.c interop2f.o -lgfortran && ./a.out
 Teststuff
   100.00000000000000     
   123.00000000000000     
   456.00000000000000     
   789.00000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks for giving credit to my Discourse post. One thing I would suggest but didn't bother to implement there was error checking. The caller should verify the object creation was successful (pointer is not null) and/or the manipulation routines should check the pointer is associated first before trying to dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Fortran 2018 standard, allocatable arrays are interopable with C, but this requires more complex stuff on the C side. The underlying question here is "do you really need to equivalence an allocatable array with the C side"? In your case (calling Fortran from C) this would be useful if you were allocating the array on the Fortran side, which is not what you are doing. Otherwise passing simple arrays is simpler, and enough.

Also, in the previous questions/answers you have been told to declare the interoperable variables with the interoperable types (`real(c_double)` instead of `real(8)`...).

Last, you are using the so-called "Cray pointers", which is a non-standard extension to Fortran that was very popular in the past. Although widely supported, there is no reason to continue using them in new code, as standard modern Fortran has everything needed in terms of pointers.

Again, the solution is using `c_ptr`, and pass the size of the array (I am using only one structure level).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    struct t_stuff {
      char   name[256];
      double extra;
      double* p_var;
      int varsize;
    };
    void test2(t_stuff *stuff);
}

int main()
{
    t_stuff stuff;

    strcpy_s(stuff.name, sizeof(stuff.name), "Teststuff");
    stuff.extra = 100.0;
    stuff.p_var = new double[2];
    stuff.varsize = 2;
    stuff.p_var[0] = 123.0;
    stuff.p_var[1] = 456.0;
    test2(&stuff);
}
```

```
module ftncode_mod
   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
   implicit none

!--external structure, same as C
   type, public, bind(C) :: t_stuff
     character(1)     :: name(256)
     real(c_double)   :: extra
     real(c_ptr)      :: varptr
     integer(c_int)   :: varsize
   end type t_stuff_gef

   contains
      subroutine test2(stuff) bind(C)
      !DEC$ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: test2
        type(t_stuff), intent(in) :: stuff
        ! var is a pointer to an array
        real(c_double), pointer :: var(:)
        integer :: n, i
        
        ! convert the C pointer to the Fortran pointer, using the size of the array
        n = stuff%varsize
        call c_f_pointer(stuff%varptr,var,[n])

        do i = 1, n
          print *, var(i)
        enddo
      end

end module
```

### Passing the array in the arguments

This is even simpler to pass directly the array instead of passing the structure:

```
...
    void test3(double *stuff,int *n);
...
int main()
{
...
    test3(stuff.p_var,&stuff.varsize);
}
```

```
...
      subroutine test3(var,n) bind(C)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real(c_double), intent(in) :: var(n)
        integer :: i
        
        do i = 1, n
          print *, var(i)
        enddo
      end
...
```

Comment: I had to do my original way as the internal Fortran structures (which I have to use) contain allocatable arrays.  So these need to be part of this simplified example.

Comment: Then, you have either to duplicate the data as in your original code (but still, prefer using `c_ptr` instead of Cray pointers), or to use the more complex Fortran 2018 stuff to interoperate allocatable arrays. Note that the data duplication is simpler, and perfectly reasonnable if the volume is limited.

Comment: @Adrian actually, if you have to deal with a Fortran library with types that you can't modify, I am not sure there's a solution to access the allocatable array components from the C side. In this case data duplication is probably needed...

Comment: yes, this is the case - Also I am using sequence instead of bind(C) to ensure the structure elements line up correctly and also on 8 byte boundaries.

Comment: Be aware that C interfacing solutions that do not use the C binding features are non-standard and therefore not portable: nothing ensures that it will work with another compiler, or even with future versions of the same compiler.

Comment: @Adrian I have asked on the Fortran Discourse, and someone came up with a possible solution that avoids data duplication: https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/allocate-interoperability-and-c-descriptors/5088 (you have to scroll down for the allocatable-in-a-type case). This solution is not applicable in all cases, but sometimes it is.

Comment: good old Steve!